# Piecewise continuity and derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

If $f'(x)$ is piecewise continuous in $[0,1]$, does it implie that $f$ is also piecewise continuous in $[0,1]$? My intuition tells me that it should be so, but I see many sentences like "Let $f$ and $f'$ be piecewise continuous."

**Edit**: $f$ is *piecewise continuous* in $[0,1]$ if there is a partition
$$0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=1$$
such that each restriction $f|_{(x_{i-1},x_i)}$ is continuous, and the one-sided limits
$$\lim_{x\to x_{i-1}^+}f(x)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to x_i^-}f(x)$$
are finite.

Comment: Existence of $f'(x)$ for all $x$ implies that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: As I understand it, "piecewise continuity" of $f$ usually tolerates $f$ being not defined at finitely many points.

Comment: For each piece (interval) where $f'$ exists, $f$ is continuous on that piece.

Comment: @Angryavia : You are right. How silly of me. I will delete my question shortly.

Comment: @Angryavia : Actually, piecewise continuity also requires finite one-sided limits. Maybe it is possible that one-sided limits of $f'$ exist while one-sided limits of $f$ do not?

Comment: Can you say precisely what you mean by "piecewise continuous", in the body of your question?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer. I am simply sharing my thoughts. Could you think about the following situation?

1. $f(0)= 0$
2. $f^1$ is integrable

In that case, it's clear that $f$ is, in fact, continuous everywhere on $[0, 1$ because integration is a smooth operator ie takes an integrable function and return continuous function. Please don't get me wrong.